# What is "T _fcntl$NOCANCEL" in nodejs, and what potential optimizations could it imply?

Tags: node.js, profiling, v8

Frequently (perhaps always?), when profiling a node.js application, I see the mysterious `T _fcntl$NOCANCEL` at the top of the list as taking up the most ticks. My current profiling task has it as taking up almost 20% of the CPU time. I know this is probably in reference to the POSIX `fnctl` function, but I have no idea what this actually *means* as to what's going on in my app. The "bottom-up" output from the profiling doesn't show it as having any parent caller.

What does `T _fcntl$NOCANCEL` signify? Does this hint at any typical sorts of optimizations that can be done? Is there any way for me to get more detailed information from the profiler?

Answer (score 1):

`fnctl` is a POSIX syscall (https://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl) used to perform operations on file handles. This means you're probably doing a lot of filesystem operations. If you're curious about reducing its usage, you can probably use `strace` to see the calls to `fnctl` are actually doing.